# upload a javascript File object through an iFrame

Tags: javascript, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a drag and drop file upload UI. The problem is that I have to submit the files using an old fashioned multipart form. Is it possible to take the File objects you get from a drop event and somehow insert them into a form so they can be submitted to an iFrame like file inputs?

Comment: I would suggest going back to your previous questions and marking answers as 'the answer'.  You have quite a low score of 22%.  Not many people are going to be willing to answer your question because you aren't likely to mark there answer as "correct" if it's correct.

Comment: I was just looking at that. Is that what that means? I'll take a look and see if any of my questions have been answered that I haven't marked. Thanks.

Comment: 90%!  Much better!  I hope you get plenty of help of SO!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **have to** submit via a multi-part form, then no, there's no cross-browser way to do this.  Browsers will not let JavaScript code update the value of any "file" input elements, for reasons that should be obvious (security - if your code code set a "file" input to any path, well ...).

There are newer ways of handling files, but in general there's still no way to create or copy a "file" element with a value.